# how copy data from one timestamp to another timestamp in sql statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The case is that:
For example: we have a table which store all the historical data.
Here is input:(treat below data like database table)
[image]

I want to output to be break down by day
Output:
[image]

Comment: Generate calendar table and use it as a base for updating.

Comment: mysql, sql-server, google-bigquery - select only one DBMS and remove unrelated tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use `generate_date_array` and `unnest`:

```
with mytable as (
  select 123 as student_id, 'math' as subject, 80 as score, date '2019-11-11' as update_time union all
  select 123, 'math', 92, date '2019-11-15' union all
  select 123, 'math', 93, date '2019-11-17' union all
  select 123, 'english', 81, date '2019-11-11' union all
  select 123, 'english', 85, date '2019-11-15' union all
  select 124, 'math', 80, date '2019-11-11' union all
  select 124, 'math', 92, date '2019-11-15' union all
  select 124, 'english', 81, date '2019-11-11' union all
  select 124, 'english', 85, date '2019-11-15'
)
select student_id, subject, score, ifnull(generated_date, update_time) as update_time
from (
  select
    *,
    generate_date_array(update_time, date_sub(lead(update_time) over (partition by student_id, subject order by update_time), interval 1 day)) as generated_dates
  from mytable
) left join unnest(generated_dates) as generated_date
```

[image]